# Shiny Widgits for scratch

Tags: r, shiny, shinydashboard, shinyjs, shinyapps

I am planning to make ShinyWidgits from scratch so that I can use it as a reusable component in other shiny apps. I have search from resources ([this](https://github.com/rstudio/rmdexamples) n [this](https://github.com/dreamRs/shinyWidgets)) for the same but haven't found legitimate resources so far. It would be great if anyone can point me to some resources. TIA

Comment: have a look at this https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/js-build-widget.html

Comment: If I am not wrong, HtmlWidgits and shinywidgits are two different things. @PorkChop

Comment: `htmlwidgets` is framework for embedding JavaScript visualizations into R. https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/htmlwidgets.html `shinywidgits` is a package, that was written by the guys from France, that is all. If you want to build some JS components from scratch or use some libraries you should use the link I posted earlier

Comment: Initially, I was trying to accomplish things by that way but I ran into a problem to use SVG image with HTMLWIdgets. It would be great if can help me with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60736116/using-svg-image-in-htmlwidget). Thanks

Comment: Feel free to post all your code and everything you have tried so far